# Relationships between points lines and planes

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

Develop the Cartesian equation of a plane with $x$-intercept $a$, $y$-intercept $b$ and $z$-intercept $c$. 
Show that the distance $d$ from the origin to this plane is given by $$\frac{1}{d^2}=\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}$$

In the picture below I have included what I have done so far. I was able to set all my variables and begin to define them.

[image]

Comment: Note that $d \not = \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ since $1/a=1/b+1/c \leftrightarrow a=\frac{1}{1/b+1/c} \not = b+c$

Comment: The equation for $d$ that they gave you is not a very good one because it doesn't work if $a$ or $b$ or $c$ is zero.

Comment: I suppose your statement $\vec n =(a,b,c)$ says that the normal of the plane is $(a,b,c)$. This is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another attempt, since the OP finds my first answer confusing ...

Let $A = (a,0,0)$, $B = (0,b,0)$, $C = (0,0,c)$. The normal to the plane is in the direction $N = (B-A)\times(C-A) = (bc, ca, ab)$. A unit vector in this direction is
$$
U = \frac{N}{\|N\|} = \frac{(bc,ca,ab)}{\sqrt{b^2c^2 + c^2a^2 + a^2b^2}}
$$ 
The distance $d$ from the origin to the plane is the length of the projection of $\vec{OA}$ onto the vector $U$. Since $U$ is a unit vector, this projected length is just  $A \cdot U$. So, we have
$$
d = A \cdot U = \frac{abc}{\sqrt{b^2c^2 + c^2a^2 + a^2b^2}}
$$
This formula is correct even if one of $a$, $b$, $c$ is zero and the other two are non-zero, in which case it gives $d=0$, as you would expect.

If $a$, $b$, $c$ **are all non-zero**, this formula can be rearranged to give
$$
\frac{1}{d^2} = \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} + \frac{1}{c^2}
$$

Comment: very graciously I thank you, I was able to clear up my confusion by your second explanation. Million times thanks

Answer (score 1):

Normal to the plane, using the position vectors of the intercepts given, is the vector $$\left(\begin{matrix}a\\-b\\0\end{matrix}\right)\times\left(\begin{matrix}a\\0\\-c\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}bc\\ac\\ab\end{matrix}\right)$$

This vector is parallel to $$\left(\begin{matrix}\frac 1a\\ \frac 1b\\ \frac 1c\end{matrix}\right)$$

Now the distance from the origin to the plane is the **projection** of $\overrightarrow{OA}$ onto this normal, and $\overrightarrow{OA}\cdot\underline{n}=1$.

Therefore $$d=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}}}$$

And hence the result...

Comment: if you plug that d value back in it would not equal each other I got. a^2+b^2+c^2=1/a^2+b^2+c^2

Comment: @J.io You have some wrong statements in your attempted solution. The statement $d=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ is definitely wrong. For the example $a=b=c=1$ that formula for $d$ is too large by a factor of $3$.

Comment: I don't see how you get the equation following "therefore" directly from the one before it.

Comment: @bubba I have edited my answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = (a,0,0)$, $B = (0,b,0)$, $C = (0,0,c)$. The normal to the plane is in the direction $N = (B-A)\times(C-A) = (bc, ca, ab)$. The plane passes through the point $A$, so its equation is $(X-A)\cdot N =0$. Note that $A \cdot N = abc$, so this can also be written as:
$$
bcx + cay + abz = abc
$$
The line through the origin normal to the plane has equation $L(t) = tN$. Where this line intersects the plane we get a point $F$. This is the "foot" of the normal from the origin to the plane, so it's the point of the plane that's closest to the origin. At $F$, we have $(tN - A) \cdot A = 0$. This gives $t = (A \cdot N)/(N \cdot N) = abc/(N \cdot N)$, so the intersection point is 
$$
F = \frac{abc}{N \cdot N}N = \frac{abc}{\| N \|^2}N
$$
The distance $d$ from the origin to $F$ is given by
$$
d = \|F\| = \frac{abc}{\| N \|^2}\|N\| = \frac{abc}{\| N \|}
= \frac{abc}{\sqrt{b^2c^2 + c^2a^2 + a^2b^2}}
$$
This formula is correct even if one of $a$, $b$, $c$ is zero and the other two are non-zero, in which case it gives $d=0$, as you would expect.

If $a$, $b$, $c$ **are all non-zero**, this formula gives
$$
\frac{1}{d^2} = \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} + \frac{1}{c^2}
$$

Comment: Im sorry if this sounds stupid but the answer that "bubba" has given and the answer that "David Quinn" has given are different could someone clarify for me. I partially understand what "David Quinn" has done but "bubba" answer has confused me

Comment: The equations for $d$ in the two answers are equivalent, except that David Quinn's answer doesn't work if any of $a$, $b$, $c$ is zero.

Comment: What's confusing about my answer?